# How can the subpages of pageview monitor page switching in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listener, flutter-pageview

```
PageView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => pages[index],
      itemCount: pages.length,
      controller: _pageController,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
      },
    )
```

**when pageChanged,i wish item can know it was been disPlayed or hidden,so I can do something
maybe i need a listener? but I don't know how to code,some one help me!**

Comment: use `AnimatedBuilder` and pass `animation:  _pageController` in the constructor

Comment: i forgot to add that you should use that `AnimatedBuilder` inside `itemBuilder`

Comment: thanks ,can you describe more detail?

Comment: @zerongjiang Can you exactly describe what you want to do with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

That is nothing but a standard state-passing problem. In your widget building this PageView (say, MyHomePage), you hold your `_selectedIndex` as your state. On the other hand, you want to pass this state down into some widgets inside `page[index]`. Thus, you want to *pass down a state to a child*.

There are really a lot of ways to do so. Try to search **state management**. You can use a heavy (but beautiful) lib like Mobx. You can also use lightweight things like InheritedWidget.

Comment: @zerongjiang You are welcome :) If my answer helps you, you can click the "accept this answer" at the left of this answer